# Add some default extension to executable search

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu on Windows after the  Creators Update and I noticed that now it can run Windows native Exe. It also includes by default the Windows Path at the end of the Ubuntu Path, allowing you to access all the Windows utilities right from the start.

The only problem is that Windows executable have the extension (.exe), so if for example I have 7z for Windows in the path, in the bash I still have to type

```
7z.exe
```

To use it.

I would like to set it in some way as to type

```
7z
```

and he looks for both `7z` and `7z.exe`.

Is there a way to add one or more default extensions, like saying "if you don't find it as I wrote it, try adding this extension(s) at the end"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to lose the default command-not-found features (which look up packages providing the command, etc.), then define a `command_not_found_handle` function which tests if a `.exe` version is available in the `PATH`:

```
command_not_found_handle ()
{
    if command -v "$1".exe; then
        "$1".exe "${@:2}";
        return $?;
    else
        return 127;
    fi
}
```

For example, testing with `sh` instead of `.exe`:

```
$ z
z: command not found
$ command_not_found_handle () { if command -v "$1"sh; then "$1"sh "${@:2}"; return $?; else return 127; fi; }
$ z -c 'echo "$@"' _ b c
/usr/bin/zsh
b c
$ ba -c 'echo "$@"' _ b c
/bin/bash
b c
```

<strike>Of course, this depends on how WSL is hooking into bash to provide access to the Windows commands (if WSL is using `command_not_found_handle` itself, then this won't work).</strike> Tested on WSL, it works.

---

The original, default, definition of `command_not_found_handle` is in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
$ tail -15 /etc/bash.bashrc
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
        function command_not_found_handle {
                # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                else
                   printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
                   return 127
                fi
        }
fi
```

You can just include that code in the redifinition:

```
command_not_found_handle ()
{
    if command -v "$1".exe; then
        "$1".exe "${@:2}";
        return $?;
    else
        # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
        if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
           return $?
        elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
           return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    fi
}
```

Or, use [this trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29742/70524) to automatically insert the old definition:

```
eval "original_$(declare -f command_not_found_handle)"
command_not_found_handle () {
    if command -v "$1".exe; then
        "$1".exe "${@:2}";
        return $?;
    else
        original_command_not_found_handle "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: I like as a solution, but losing the original functionality is something I would prefer to avoid. Thanks.

Comment: @bracco23 updated to retain original functionality

Comment: Well, i just tried the copy-pasted version in my `bash.bashrc` file and it works like a charm! I just redirected the ouput of `command` in the `if` condition to `/dev/null` to avoid having the path printed on screen. Thanks!

Comment: brilliant......